# Symfony FOSElasticaBundle configuration

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I am having a problem.

- **Symfony:** 4.4
- **Elasticsearch:** 7.6.1
- **FOSElasticaBundle:** 5.1
- **PHP:** 7.2.26

**My configuration:**

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
    indexes:
        app:
            finder: ~
            types:
                city:
                    properties:
                        name: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: App\Entity\City
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
```

**Command:**

```
php bin/console fos:elastica:populate
```

**Error:**

```
Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [city : {dynamic_date_formats=[], _meta={model=App\Entity\City}, properties={name={type=text}}}] [reason: Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root map
  ping definition has unsupported parameters:  [city : {dynamic_date_formats=[], _meta={model=App\Entity\City}, properties={name={type=text}}}]]
```

Comment: I have the same issue for elasticsearch 7. I used 6.8 to solve the problem. but i want to use elasticsearch 7. Do you find solution on this issue?